# Why is downcasting required after instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

Why do we need to downcast using the keyword as after instantiating a view controller with UIStoryboard's `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` method in order for the view controller's properties to be accessible?  The UIStoryboard method `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` already returns a `UIViewController` and knows which class based on the **Storyboard ID** or this is what I assume happens but not totally true.

The following code works and compiles but I want to understand why. If I were building this based on the documentation, I wouldn't have assumed downcasting would be necessary so I'm trying to figure out what part I haven't learned or understood in regards to types and/or objects being returned from functions.

```
func test_TableViewIsNotNilOnViewDidLoad() {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController")

        let sut = viewController as! ItemListViewController

        _ = sut.view

        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.tableView)

    }
```

Comment: Because `withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController"` refers to the View Controller's Identity in the storyboard and returns `UIViewController` Class type, it does not returns `UIViewController ` Class associated with it. So by Down-casting, we are assigning Class to it.

Comment: Just read the declaration! `func instantiateViewController(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController` Pretty simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `storyboard.instantiateViewController...` always returns a UIViewController (the base class for your specific subclass) and thus cannot know implementation details specific to your subclass.

The method mentioned above doesn't infer your sub-class type based on the storyboard id, this is something you do in your code when downcasting (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller)).

```
func instantiateViewController(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UIViewController
```

So it works because you get an `UIViewController` from the method above and then you force downcast it to your `ItemListViewController` (it always works because you defined `ItemListViewController` as an `UIViewController` subclass).

PS. I'm not sure I've understood your question though, this seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: I misread or basically misunderstood this line in the given reference: "This identifier is not a property of the view controller object itself and is used only by the storyboard file to locate the view controller."  Okay okay I'm learning, much much appreciated so I can move forward.

Answer (score 1):

> knows which class based on the Storyboard ID

This is completely incorrect. The Storyboard ID is a string. In your case it happens to be a static string, but this method doesn't require that. It could be computed at run time (and I've personally written code that does that). Your string happens to match the classname, but there's no requirement that this be true. The identifier can be any string at all. And the storyboard isn't part of the compilation process. The storyboard could easily be changed between the time the code is compiled and the time it's run such that the object in question has a different type.

Since there isn't enough information to compute the class at compile time, the compiler requires that you explicitly promise that it's going to work out and to decide what to do if it fails. Since you use `as!`, you're saying "please crash if this turns out to be wrong."

Comment: I like this, using optional as seems more of a way to be more safe than sorry to avoid any error or the app crashing.  Much obliged

Answer (score 1):

You maybe need to do some background reading on object oriented programming in general to help you understand. Key concepts are class, instance/object, inheritance, and polymorphism.

`storyboard.instantiateViewController()` will create an instance of `ItemListViewController` but it is being returned as `UIViewController`. If this part is difficult to understand then this is where you need objected oriented knowledge background.
In OO languges, like C++ for example, an instance of a class (also known as an object) can be referenced by a pointer to its parent (or grandparent or great grand parent etc.) class. In the majority of  literature and tutorials on object orientation the concept on inheritance and casting and polymorphism is always illustrated using pointers to base classes and derived objects and so on.
However with Swift, pointers aren't exposed in the way there are in many other OO languages.

In your code, and explaining this in a simplified way and *as if* it was C++ or a similar OO language as that is how most tutorials on OO explain things:

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController")
```

`viewController` is a "pointer" of class type `UIViewController` which is pointing to an object of type `ItemListViewController`.

The compiler sees the pointer `viewController` as being of type `UIViewController` and therefore it does not know about any of the specific methods or properties of `ItemListViewController` unless you explicitly do the cast so that it knows about them.

Comment: Just opened my eyes 100x's better to understand how class inheritance can be used and is used in regards to Apple's API's.  Much obliged

Answer (score 1):

This is partially due to polymorphism. Take for example the following code:

```
class Person { 
    let name: String
}

class Student: Person {
    let schoolName: String
}

func createRandomPerson(tag: Int) -> Person {
    if tag == 1 { return Person() }
    else { return Student() }
}

let p = createRandomPerson(2)
```

Depending on the value of the `tag` parameter you'll get either a `Person` or a `Student`.

Now if you pass `2` to the function, then you can be sure that `createRandomPerson` will return a `Student` instance, but you will still need to downcast as there are scenarios where `createRandomPerson` will return an instance of the base class.

Similar with the storyboard, you know that if you pass the correct identifier you'll get the view controller you expect, however since the storyboard can create virtually any instance of `UIViewController` subclasses (or even `UIViewController`) the function in discussion has the return type set to `UIViewController`.

And similarly, if you do your math wrong - i.e. you pass `1` to `createRandomPerson()`, or wrong identifier to the storyboard, then you won't receive what you expect to.

Comment: seems legit so for example let's say I haven't done the downcasting process.  Is there a way or a name for the process that I can use for troubleshooting a variable to see what type it is if I'm unsure of its type in swift?  Maybe have the console spit out what type it is for troubleshooting purposes?

Comment: You can check via  the `is` operator - `viewController is MyViewController`, or via an `if-let`: `if let castedController = viewController as? MyViewController { good controller } else { bad controller }`